# $\Delta_g f = 0$ on the Riemannian Manifold $(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B , g)$ with conditions on the boundary and at infinity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, asymptotics, geometric-analysis

Consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B$ where $B$ is the ball with radius 1 with riemannian metric $g$ (not necessarily the euclidean metric).

I am looking for solutions to $\Delta_g f = 0$ where $f \to 1$ at infinity and $f=f_0$ on $\partial M$ where $f_0$ is some positive function on $∂M$.

1) What can we say about existence and uniqueness of this PDE? Any simple proofs?

2) What can we say about the asymptotic behaviour of f at infinity?

I think if g is the euclidean metric, the asymptotics are:
$$f = 1+ \frac{C}{r} + O \left( \frac{1}{r^{2}} \right)$$
where $C$ is some constant and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ in cartesian coordinates. (Check chapter 2.17 in The Laplace Equation by Dagmar Medkova).

3) What if g is asymptotically flat? (so in cartesian coordinates, the metric satisfies $ g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + O \left( \frac{1}{r^{\delta}} \right) $ for some $\delta > 0$).

Any help is appreciated. If you know any references, please share it with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find a full treatement of this problem in: [The Mass of Asymptotically Flat Manifold](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math646/bartnik.mass.pdf), by Bartnik. Becarefull there is a small error, the decay rate of $f-1$ can't be better than $\frac{1}{r}$, that is to say the one of the Green function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I researched a lot but didn’t run into that paper.  I didn’t get what you were saying; you mean an error in the paper by Bartnik? Ill read this paper soon then maybe I’ll understand what you were saying. Thank you.

Comment: ALready speak about this in my post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291763/harmonic-coordinates-on-asymptotically-flat-manifold
It is in theorem 3.1, the decreasing is to good, it can exceed $r^{2-n}$ especialy when $\tau$ is big, which is perfectly ok for the rest a the paper which is a master piece